# Groovy default method parameters

Tags: groovy, overloading

How to call the below method def to pass only *interactionId, transactionId, awResponseFile,  testMethodName and expectedNumberOfConsumers*?

**method def**

```
void verifyPersistence(String interactionId, String transactionId, 
                       File rawResponseFile, String testMethodName, 
                       int expectedNumberOfDatasourceProductResponseRaws=1, 
                       String dsProductName=datasourceSpec['creditreport.name'], 
                       int expectedNumberOfDatasourceProductResponses=1, 
                       int expectedNumberOfConsumers=1, 
                       int expectedNumberOfAddresses=1 )
```

**method call**

```
verifyPersistence interactionId.persistedVersion(), transactionId, 
                  results, testName.methodName, expectedNumberOfConsumers:8
```

**Exception**

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: verifyPersistence() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File, java.lang.String) values: [[expectedNumberOfConsumers:8], 3130001030065, 10003000000890059, C:\results, multiple consumers contracts]
Possible solutions: 

verifyPersistence(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File, java.lang.String), 
verifyPersistence(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File, java.lang.String, int), 
verifyPersistence(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String), 
verifyPersistence(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, int), verifyPersistence(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, int, int)
    at HitmultipleconsumersPersistSpec.groovy:151)
```

Comment: Is it not possible to pass the other params as `null`?

Comment: @iberbeu no. others should still take the default values provided in the method def. do u know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the first parameter should be a `String` but you are introducing a `LinkedHashMap` are you sure `interactionId.persistedVersion()` is returning a `String` and not a `LinkedHashMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you include a map entry (`key:value`), they get automatically collected, put into a hashmap and passed as the first parameter. Groovy, right now, doesn't have named parameters. For that specific case, i think you are better using a map for that method:

```
def verifyPersistence(Map map) {
  String interactionId = map.interactionId
  String transactionId = map.transactionId
  File rawResponseFile = map.rawResponseFile
  String testMethodName = map.testMethodName
  int expectedNumberOfDatasourceProductResponseRaws = map.expectedNumberOfDatasourceProductResponseRaws ?: 1
  String dsProductName = map.dsProductName ?: datasourceSpec['creditreport.name']
  int expectedNumberOfDatasourceProductResponses = map.expectedNumberOfDatasourceProductResponses ?: 1
  int expectedNumberOfConsumers = map.expectedNumberOfConsumers ?: 1
  int expectedNumberOfAddresses = map.expectedNumberOfAddresses ?: 1
}


verifyPersistence(
  interactionId : interactionId.persistedVersion(), 
  transactionId : transactionId, 
  rawResponseFile : results, 
  expectedNumberOfDatasourceProductResponseRaws : 14, 
  expectedNumberOfConsumers:8
)
```

You obviously don't need to assign every parameter to a variable, you can simply use the `map.field` syntax. If you want it to be type checked, then i think you are better using an object to encapsulate the parameters.

Comment: The problem with map parameters, is that you lose the code completion, type checking and standard way of documenting parameters. You can not have default keys (without using unsightly patterns), and you get no warning if you mistyped a key name.

Comment: @ddimitrov, of course, it is a syntactic sugar over a key->value map. For type checking and auto completion, i'd recommend going for a class to specify params, like: `parse(new Param(host: "10.1.1.1", port: 9000))`